# Android bug testing - javascript enabled not working on phones with sdk 6.0 and higher

Tags: javascript, java, android

I have been building an android app.  It works great except, I decided to bug test on other devices.  Found a bug I have spent 2 days trying to work through.

When I test on devices below 6.0, works great.  Tested all the way down to 4.0.

The Problem:
When I test on devices using android 6.0 or higher, javascript stops working within a webview.

This webview is html css and javascript loading from asset folder.

The question:
Are there any tricks for loading javascript from webview on devices using 6.0 or higher?

Here is the info from the java file:

```
     WebView webView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
     WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
     String myurl="file:///android_asset/index.html";
     webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
     webSettings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
     webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
     webView.loadUrl(myurl);
```

Comment: Something to note, I have been through every forum post related to this topic.  Loading setDomStroage did not help.

Answer (score 0):

can you show us the log when your app crashing? to help you answer clearer.

for your information, since android 6.0, the app must ask permission to user when app is running, not when they installed the app.
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Hi dhanial,

The app is not crashing at all.  It even shows the html5.  But none of the javascript is working like it is in 4.0 5.0 5.1 and the other sdks using.

The javascript stops functioning when I get to 6.0, like it is not loading anymore.  Yet when i view the app on 5.0, works great.

Comment: can you log it, better if you show the log when on processing the javascript

Comment: ok i will show you logs of it working in 5.1 and not working in 7,1

Comment: as i read in https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html
is your code in java appended annotation @JavascriptInterface?